# R: Not all categorical variable levels are shown in the summary output of my GLM model

Tags: r, formatting, categorical-data

I have a variable called experience which was coded as numeric and contains 3 values (1,5,10). I changed the class to factor using `df$experience<-factor(df$experience)` and it changed to factor. 
Next I run a GLM model as

```
reg<-glm(cbind(win,loss)~experience, data=df, family=binomial)
```

but when I get `summary(reg)`, only one level of the experience variable shows in the table (i.e. `experience10`).
Shouldn't there also be another categorical variable, `experience5`?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26539/11849

Comment: The categorical variable experience has 3 levels, shouldn't 2 of these levels be shown in the summary output? I understand that I will have a base case (for example experience1) which will not be shown in the output. But I am only getting one level which is the experience10. Thanks.

Comment: We can't help you without a [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059) example.

Answer (score 0):

After using sub-samples of my data, the other levels were showing up. I guess it was just a matter of Multicollinearity where the other level was not being calculated somehow!
Thanks!